# Build libdav1d using Microsoft Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, build, ninja, meson-build

I've managed to [build it using MinGW](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d/-/wikis/compilation-guide).

Is there a way to build it using `Microsoft Visual C++`?

I want to use it with `FFmpeg`. My FFmpeg and all its dependencies are compiled using Visual C++, so I'm trying to avoid [possible problems caused by mixing MinGW and Visual C++ libraries](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fbe17181-0da0-4266-9370-efb5443a34fe/how-to-convert-the-libx264a-to-libx264lib?forum=vcgeneral).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I've found a working solution.

1. Install Meson (https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/releases)
2. Install NASM (https://www.nasm.us/)
3. Add both Meson and NASM to system PATH variable
4. Open x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for Visual Studio (to build x64 version)
5. Apply the following commands:

`git clone https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d.git`

`cd dav1d`

`meson build`

`cd build`

`meson configure -Dbuildtype=release`

`meson configure -Ddefault_library=static`

`ninja`

But for an unknown reason it generates static libraries with `.a` extension instead of `.lib`. I think it's just a typo and it's safe to just rename the generated lib.

To generate shared library use `meson configure -Ddefault_library=shared`.